# File generated by MySQL outfile with a line start string

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

How can I start my file generated by MySQL outfile with a specific string?

I am currently using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rmssettings
INTO OUTFILE 'F:\\Assignment\\VIEWS1.sql'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES STARTING BY 'Insert' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the string that you want to start with look like ?

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT "foo, bar, baz, hello\n", rmssettings.* FROM rmssettings
INTO OUTFILE 'F:\\Assignment\\VIEWS1.sql'
...
```